# Trying to add sort order to a responsive Flickr gallery (jQuery) that's no longer supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, flickr

Preface: I'm a newb jQuery "developer".

I purchased a jQuery Flickr gallery called "Responsive Flickr Gallery". It works great, and the developer was helpful and active with fixing issues, etc., but then he disappeared. I'm still using the gallery (example: http://www.jamiegphotography.com/Galleries/Events/Concert-Intersection-Camera2-Parachute-Walk-Off-the-Earth.aspx), and have done a bit of customizing (mainly via CSS), but one thing it does not do is sort the photos by date. It was a feature many people were asking for, before he left. I am pretty sure Flickr has sorting parameters available, but I'm not sure how to begin implementing anything into the gallery.

I'm not sure the best way to provide what I've got so far. Here is a link to a fiddle of the main .js file (rfg.js):

http://jsfiddle.net/jag64551/9kh7Q/1/ (a portion of the code below)

Other files available include lightbox.js, lightbox.min.js, rfg.min.js. If you need to see anything else, let me know.

Sorry for just throwing this out there. At this point in my knowledge, I don't really know where to begin. Any help would be appreciated!

```
//Default options (all can be overridden)
rfg.defaults = {
    categories:true,
    flickrSets:[],
    flickrOptions: {
        useTitle: false,
        imageSize: 'm'
    },
    categoryOptions:{
        includeAll:true,
        defaultCategory:false
    },
    lightbox:true,
    imageWidth:300,
    spacing:10,
    center:true,
    initialHeight:0
};
```

Comment: From flickr api docs: sort (Opcional)
The order in which to sort returned photos. Deafults to date-posted-desc (unless you are doing a radial geo query, in which case the default sorting is by ascending distance from the point specified). The possible values are: date-posted-asc, date-posted-desc, date-taken-asc, date-taken-desc, interestingness-desc, interestingness-asc, and relevance.

Comment: Thanks Robert - I had tried adding

    sort: 'date-posted-dsc',

to the flickrOptions: section, but I believe that the plugin is set to load images randomly.

Comment: I believe starting line 514, the plugin overrides standard sorting, with randomizing code, but I'm not sure what to do with it - http://jsfiddle.net/jag64551/9kh7Q/1/

Comment: You are ussing the flickr.photosets.getPhotos method...for sorting you should use flickr.photos.search in order to use date-posted-dsc parameter